# The maths needed for stopping camera going through walls with three.js

Tags: three.js, game-development

I have edited a example on three.js : https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html

I have changed the collisions so that whenever they walk through it detects not only jumping ontop.

My problem is i don't know how to make it so it stops the player from going through the block. If somebody could help me out with that it would be greatly appreciated. I'm only a beginner in three.js.

Comment: Use `THREE.Raycaster()`.

Comment: That us what i am using

Comment: My source code is hosted on apache on my vps here: http://51.38.36.156/ and look into the index.html file

Comment: _Nobody_ in their right mind is going to follow a link to a random IP address. Please build a minimal example or copy your code to a reliable host, like StackOverflow snippets, JSFiddle, CodePen, Plnkr, etc.

Comment: I think you'll need more detail in this question, including attempts so far, to get a detailed answer, but here is one more thing worth trying: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-pathfinding. The `clampStep` function can be used to constrain FPS-style movement.